# Authorization point produces 404 but is specified in well-known config in IDS4

Tags: c#, authorization, identityserver4

I'm running a project trying to obtain access token following the authorization code workflow following [this blog](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4#API). Going to the address

> https://localhost:44300/.well-known/openid-configuration

I get a listing saying that

> "authorization_endpoint": "https://localhost:44300/connect/authorize", ...

However, when I try to [access that endpoint](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html) (GET in PostMan and from browser), I get status code 404. I go for the

> "token_endpoint":"https://localhost:44300/connect/token"

and it works dandy, just as supposed to. I've tried to specify the parameters in query string [as suggested](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/authorize.html#authorization-endpoint) using the extension method `CreateAuthorizeUrl(...)` with no difference. Googling for *ids4 authorization 404 not found* gave only hits on borken routing, in which case even token endpoint would suffer.

There was a suggestion to implement our own, custom, endpoint but that defeats the whole purpose of ID Server (and I do trust that those guys know better than I, anyway).

We made really sure that the endpoint is exposed (setting to false hides it from the well-known).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddIdentityServer(opt => opt.Endpoints.EnableAuthorizeEndpoint = true)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Clients.Obtain())
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdResources.Obtain())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(ApiResources.Obtain())
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(ApiScopes.Obtain())
    .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Obtain().ToList())
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}
```

And then nothing else than routing and IDS (including a gazillion different combinations of adding/moving `AddAuthentication()`, `AddAutheorization()`, `.AddDefaultEndpoints()` etc.).

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseIdentityServer();
}
```

We've emptied the whole team's wits on that. What would be a wise approach to trouble-shoot it?

Comment: Did you possibly register MVC before IDS4 in the pipeline?

Comment: @mackie Yes, I did. I go *app.UseIdentityServer()* and after that *app.UseMvc()*. I wanted the security to kick in **before** the call is routed to the data source. Am I confusing concepts?

Comment: @mackie I'm referring to [the last code snippet in *Adding UI* section](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html#adding-the-ui) of the docs. As you see there, they add the IDS first and then jack in the MVC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the authorization endpoint fails validation, [IdentityServer4 will redirect the user to your error page](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Endpoints/Results/AuthorizeResult.cs#L91). By default, this is `/Home/Error`. If this error page does not exist, then the 302 redirect will result in a 404.

Otherwise, when you hit the authorization endpoint, what do your logs say? IdentityServer should give you an error log for the authorization endpoint and the ASP.NET Core should give you an info log about the 404.

Comment: I tested an empty project with your config and that's what happened. I hope it's that simple for you 

Comment: Hey. I actually follow your blog on the subject very closely, so I feel honored to see you answer here. Your answer is perfectly correct and that was indeed the sneakyness I missed. Now, that I've seen the actual error, I got my client working. There's an unclarity in the blog I praised you for regarding the next stage - a call to */connect/authorize*. Would you be open to answering that too (in a separate question) or are you good for now providing support (which I'm thankful for)?

Comment: No worries. I'll take a look!

Comment: That would be awesome. It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68400439/how-to-obtain-the-code-from-ids4-on-successful-call-to-connect-authorize) and I get it may require certain effort, possibly leading to FUQs, so it's going to be bounty on that too. Usually, I'm stingy with the rep but right now, it's an open war against IDS4 - folded twice before but I won't this time.